# Replace new JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to make JSON look like this:

```
{"tokenId":1,"uri":"ipfs://bafy...","minPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x1a"},"signature":"0x51xxx"}
```

This is my currently output:

```
 {
        "tokenId": "1",
        "uri": "ipfs://baf...",
        "minPrice": 0.26,
        "signature": "0x..."
    }
```

This is the retrieve code.

```
async function redeem(cid) {
  fetch(`http://localhost:4000/getDetails/${cid}`).then(response => {
    return response.json()
  }).then((async output=> {
    console.log(output[0]); // it displays json
    const obj = output[0].minPrice.toString();
    const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(obj,2);
    console.log(price) 
  }))
```

I want to make the minPrice look same as the above, so I use `ethers.utils.parseUnits`. After converting it, how can I replace the existing minPrice with the `BigNumber` minPrice(price) so the `JSON` output will look **exactly** like the first `JSON`?

Comment: How does `0.03` become hex `0x1a`? That hex corresponds to decimal `26`.

Comment: @Barmar Amount not that important, it just an example

Comment: It's important so we understand how you're trying to translate fractions into hex integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the price to an integer by multiplying by 100. Then convert that to hex.

```
let price_cents = Math.round(output[0].minPrice * 100);
let hex_price = '0x' + price_cents.toString(16);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your number minPrice to a hex string by specifying the radix:

```js
minPrice.toString(16)
```

so probably you want something like

```js
price.minPrice = {"type": "BigNumber","hex": price.minPrice.toString(16)}
```

Comment: `(0.03).toString(16) == '0.07ae147ae147ae'`, not `0x1a`

Comment: sorry maybe you misunderstand my question..I have edited my post.